# Error: init() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'iswalking' and 'eat'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Mammals:
    def __init__(self, iswalking, eat):
        self.eat = "Eating Sausages"
        self.iswalking = True
        print("walk")

class Dog(Mammals):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = "Spiky"

pet = Dog()
print(pet.name)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\RequestDemo.py", line 12, in <module>
    pet = Dog()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\RequestDemo.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'iswalking' and 'eat'
```

Comment: Remove the `iswalking` and `eat` parameters from `Mammals.__init__`. You are not using them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Mammals:
    def __init__(self, iswalking=True, eat="Eating Sausages"):
        self.eat = eat
        self.iswalking = iswalking
        print("walk")


class Dog(Mammals):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = "Spiky"


pet = Dog()
print(pet.name)
```

Comment: kowel. what are the requirements to become a python developer ? and can i use Django for desktop and mobile applications ?

Comment: I am not a python developer. I am self-taught programmer. You better use kivy for applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Mammals:
    def __init__(self, iswalking, eat):
        self.eat = "Eating Sausages"
        self.iswalking = True
        print("walk")

class Dog(Mammals):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("",True)
        self.name = "Spiky"

pet = Dog()
print(pet.name)
```

OR

```
class Mammals:
    def __init__(self, eat="Eating Sausages", iswalking=True):
        self.eat = iswalking
        self.iswalking = eat
        print("walk")

class Dog(Mammals):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("",True)
        self.name = "Spiky"

pet = Dog()
print(pet.name)
```